# as including a gps to hector quadcopter?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm working with hector quadcopter package, and I need include a gps to hector quadcopter and transform the output of latitude and longitude in Cartesian coordinates.
any ideas?, thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6582/as-including-a-gps-to-hector-quadcopter?/) by [eduard](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/888/eduard/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is a [GPS sensor](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1sensors_1_1GpsSensor.html) in Gazebo. Here is an [example SDF](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/08e9e0ddcf229fc2fd8f97d8d384c4d7dc436553/test/worlds/gps_test.world?at=default) file that uses GPS.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1